# echo does not print a variable in bash

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I'm facing a very strange issue. I have 2 files ber_log_before.txt and ber_log_after.txt. Their contents are

ber_log_before.txt

```
$
BOAR 0 BER:14
BOAR 1 BER:19
BOAR 2 BER:0
BOAR 3 BER:0
BOAR 4 BER:0
BOAR 5 BER:0
BOAR 6 BER:0
BOAR 7 BER:0

$
```

ber_log_after.txt

```
$
BOAR 0 BER:24
BOAR 1 BER:29
BOAR 2 BER:0
BOAR 3 BER:0
BOAR 4 BER:0
BOAR 5 BER:0
BOAR 6 BER:0
BOAR 7 BER:0

$
```

There are `$` it's normal.

Then I wrote a basic bash command to parse them

```
PORT="0 1"
for port in $PORT; do
    VAL1=$(grep "BOAR $port" ber_log_before.txt | cut -f2 -d':')
    VAL2=$(grep "BOAR $port" ber_log_after.txt  | cut -f2 -d':')
    echo 1st val ${VAL1} 2em val ${VAL2}
done
```

Why `1st val 14 2em val 24` is not echoed???

If I replace

```
echo 1st val ${VAL1} 2em val ${VAL2}
```

by

```
echo 1st val ${VAL1}
echo 2em val ${VAL2}
```

Then at least I have 2em val echoed.

I guess that awk can do the job, but that's not the question.

Comment: Echos `1st val 14 2em val 24` on the first line for me. (`1st val 19 2em val 29` on the second line)

Comment: I tried with your files. As @sneep noticed the output is:

    `1st val 14 2em val 24`
    `1st val 19 2em val 29`

It seems correct to me. Can you explain better what is the problem?

Comment: Tried it locally, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem actually, or it was me the problem. both files I mentioned are created from a telnet session (with expect command to be more specific). So all lines are ending with \r and of course `echo 1st val 14\r 2em val 24\r` will 'overwrite' the first part of the echo. So I replace the \r by \n and then it's ok.

To understand the problem, I copied my command into a script and use `set -x`. It was easy to find the \r.

Sorry for that stupid question.